# Cant find either column "" or the user-defined function or aggregate "", or the name is ambiguous

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE FUNCTION Person_Details (@P_ID int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN(SELECT Person_ID,P_F_Name 
FROM Person_tbl
WHERE Person_ID=@P_ID) 

SELECT dbo.Person_Details(1)

--WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE BECAUSE IM STILL A NEWBIE
```

Comment: Read the docs.... https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Person_Details(1)
```